# OneDrive for Business: long filenames will not sync on one computer, but is ok on others

Tags: onedrive, filenames

I'm trying to sync to a Win7 64 bit computer and it stops with a "filename too long" error. However I can sync ok on any other computer I've tried. The only difference I can see is that all the ok computers are 32 bit and the error computer is 64 bit.  Any ideas please as files are nested in many sub directories and would be a big job to change?

Comment: Some more info would help here. Such as the path's in question. Also, do you have the same user names on both platforms?

Comment: Compare the length of the local OneDrive path names on the two computers.

Answer (score 3):

This could be caused by the location you are syncing to on the computer. By default the sync occurs in your user folder: C:\Users\username\

That sync folder path length is then added to the file path length you are syncing from OneDrive for Business. If it exceeds the max path length supported by Windows then it will not sync. If you have a user with a long username on one computer the files may not sync, a user with a short name may have the files sync file. Therefore this could explain the variability you are seeing.

You can change the default sync location. Ideally to a short path like c:\odb. Instructions on how to do that here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-location-where-you-sync-SharePoint-libraries-on-your-computer-ca8a88f6-bc4f-4ec2-a460-864c4e9b2be0